# Better way to assert that all user.name in an array of user start with a prefix using rspec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Here is what I have. And that kind of work.

```
it "should filter by name" do
  users = users.search(:name => "s")
  users.each {|u| 
    u.name.should be_starts_with("s")
  } 
end
```

However, the error message returned by rspec is really poor...

> expected starts_with?("s") to return true, got false

Is there a way to get a more precise message, showing the element that failed, or at least its index?

Comment: also.... I write it "filters by name" not "should filter by name"

Comment: should be_starts_with reads just horrible, too.

Comment: This also feels a bit like an api issue. users.search(:name => "s") doesn't reveal that it is a starts with. Can you do something like users.search_by_name(:starting_with => "s") ? or put a wildcard, users.search(:name => "s*")

Comment: Spec::Matchers looks a bit interesting: http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html

Comment: The Ruby method is `start_with`. `starts_with` is a Rails monkeypatch.

Comment: what I really would like to write is should start_with of course.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a binary test like this, I would create two users, one that starts with an s, the other without. I would then check that only the expected element was returned.

like

```
set up a user(:name => "Sam") and user(:name => "Fred")

filtered_users.map(&:name).should =~ ["Sam"]
```

In the case of failure, you will see something like

```
expected ["Sam"]
got ["Fred", "Sam"]
```

This is much more explicit about what you are doing

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are only getting *expected true but got false* is because the starts_with methods returns true or false and not the actual value.

I'm not sure that this is the best way, but you can output it yourself.

```
  users.each {|u| 
    p u.name if !u.name.starts_with?("s")
    u.name.should be_starts_with("s")
  }
```

Comment: I think I found a nice solution, I post it as an answer ans will wait to see what rubyist comment on my solution

Comment: This feels more like a band-aid over the problem of the test having an issue. If the failure message is not obvious, that should (and often is) a clue that the test is not written the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I used few times in cases like this:

```
describe 'user' do
  before :each do
    @users = users.search(:name => "s")
  end

  @users.each do |u| 
    it "should filter user with name '#{u.name}'" do
      u.name.should be_starts_with("s")
    end
  end

end
```

You will have failed user name in you example description.

Comment: wouldn't that run the search for each 'it "should..."' ? before :all maybe?

Comment: The let is evaluated at the same time as the examples, not at example construction time. Different scopes, so you won't have access to filtered_users while building the examples. (unless I'm reading your lack of parens and : wrong.

Comment: @coreyhaines - you'r right, let won't work in this case.before :all or before :each will.

Comment: @vanyak Not sure about that. still different scopes. The block given to before :each is executed once per example. So, the instance variable @ users isn't set until an example is run. In your code, @ users is nil, so you should get an exception if you run this. Also... you don't need the :each anymore, just do "before do"

Answer (score 0):

I found here an interesting extension to the matchers from Rspec concerning each :
http://xtargets.com/2011/08/12/rspec-meta-expectations-over-collections

So I sticked that helper into my spec_helper

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :each do |meta|
  match do |actual|
    actual.each_with_index do |i, j|
    @elem = j
    i.should meta
  end
end

failure_message_for_should do |actual|
  "at[#{@elem}] #{meta.failure_message_for_should}"
end
```

that allows me to write

```
users.should each satisfy {|u| u.name.should be_starts_with 's'}
```

and the error message is then :

> at[1] expected #User to satisfy block

which give me the first index of failure.
With some addition to the error message, I'm sure I could output the details of that object that didn't match, and that seem a pretty good solution.

Any thoughts? I'm not a rubyist, just getting started with rails. Would be nice to get more input from

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you with far better failure messages

```
it "should filter by name" do
  users = users.search(:name => "s")
  users.each do |u|
    u.name.should match /^s/
  end
end
```

I agree with Corey that calling "be_starts_with" is rough. RSpec expectations are intended to be read fluidly as a sentence. They don't all have to use "be".

Comment: Replacing `start_with?` of a string with `match` of a regular expression to satisfy rspec sounds a little Procrustean.

Comment: @Andrew: Apparently `u.name.should start_with("s")` also works.

Comment: I thought it calling should(start_with(x)) would work, too, but this was the error I received in a fresh Rails 3.1.1 app running RSpec 2.7.
`Failures:

  1) Sample does something
     Failure/Error: name.should start_with "j"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'start_with' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fa10513e2c0>
     # ./spec/models/sample_spec.rb:6:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`